# Eclipse not compiling because of ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, compilation, aspectj

After following [an AWS tutorial for Eclipse](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/setup.html), my code no longer compiles and runs.
I decided to undo what the tutorial told me, so I may have changed some settings that I forgot to unchanged but I really cannot find the root of my problem. Eclipse seems to be back to its default settings now but I still can't run a very simple class. I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /Users/myname/aspectj1/6/lib/aspectjrt/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .Users.myname.aspectj1.6.lib.aspectjrt.jar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you actually have?

Comment: Its not a problem in the individual program itself, because all projects that were open on eclipse at the time will not compile and will give that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your Eclipse doesn't found the library of `aspectj`. Try to download it again from:

https://eclipse.org/aspectj/downloads.php

By your stack trace I suppose that the version of `aspectj` that it is looking for it's the `1.6` so I suppose that you have to search the package in which puts `aspectj-1.6.0.jar` in the webpage that I put above.

**EDIT:** Look at these lines in the tutorial that you put above:

> Certain AWS Flow Framework for Java annotations such as @Asynchronous require AspectJ. You don't need to use AspectJ directly, but you must enable it with either load-time weaving or compile-time weaving.

It seems that it is necesary for AWS to the correct performance so I think you have to download the libraries of `aspectj` again.

I expect it will solve your problem!

Comment: The thing is I deleted all of my aspectj libraries, so I don't want to redownload it. I'm just struggling to understand why my programs need it to operate... they're very simple java programs? do you know how i would go about making eclipse not look for the aspectj?

Comment: I didn't saw the tutorial that you put above, I just look at the stack trace. I will see it in a few minutes. If I have another possible answer I will edit my question and contact with you. Anyway, why did you delete this libraries?

Comment: I am new to AWS and wasn't really sure what i was doing, but later found out I don't need the aspectj library for the part of AWS i will be using, so I attempted to delete the files i had downloaded/installed/configured and i guess i messed some stuff up along the way. thanks for your help!

Comment: @CodingNube13 I edited my question now. It seems that it is necesary. I'm not secure because I didn't use AWS but, like the tutorial says, you maybe won't use it directly, but you will need to use it.

Comment: Sorry for being so difficult, you are helping so much! I'm actually not using AWS at all in my programs. They are just programs in Eclipse that no longer want to work. The most simple HelloWorld program doesn't work, either. So i think the problem is in me having to configure eclipse somehow, i just don't know where to begin1

Comment: @CodingNube13 all the projects are in the same workspace? If it is, try to create your "Hello World" in another different workspace.

Comment: @CodingNube13 You are welcome ;) And please if it had been helpful for you mark it as accepted answer. Thank you!